# using custom class/function as key in sorted function

Tags: python, sorting

I generally understand how to use a `lambda` function or another array as a key to sort an array, but have a hard time understanding the following usage of custom class as a key in `sorted()` function. Could you explain how it works and why the first number printed out is 5 in the output?

```
class STR(str):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        print(self, other)
        return self + other < other + self

list_ = ['3', '30', '34', '5', '9']
sorted(list_, key=STR, reverse=True)

output:
5 9
34 5
30 34
3 30
3 5
3 34
3 30
['9', '5', '34', '3', '30']
```

However, the following code does not work well. The output is wrong. Does this mean that sorted by default uses `__lt__` rather than `__gt__` method?  Seeing from the output, `__gt__` has never been called otherwise it shall print out (self, other).

```
class STR(str):
    def __gt__(self, other):
        print(self, other)
        return self + other > other + self

list_ = ['3', '30', '34', '5', '9']
sorted(list_, key=STR, reverse=True)

output:
['9', '5', '34', '30', '3']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom class in this case is inheriting from `str` and overloading it's `__lt__` method. `__lt__()` is called when you use the less than operator. When you pass this custom class as the key in `sorted()`, it first maps your class onto the items in your list and then compares them using `<`, which calls the overloaded `__lt__()` method in your custom class. As for why it's comparing `'5'` first, it's because you specified `reverse=True` so it starts comparing from the end of the list backwards.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, it seems I am on the right track to understanding it. Could you explain further to my updated question? Thanks a lot

Comment: Python `sort()` behavior is defined here https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort. Only `<` is used to compare between items. In your updated question, overloading `__gt__()` will replace `str` default `__gt__()` method but not `__lt__()`. That's why your `sorted()` call on the updated code only outputs the list. `str` `__lt__()` is used for the sort and your overloaded `__gt__()` isn't.